# How avoid policyd track non-sent emails

Tags: smtp, limit

I have a setup with postfix, saslauthd for the auth and policyd and everything works but this problem: when I try to reach more than `smtpd_recipient_limit` recipients (ex. limit 50 and I try to send to 55 dest) policyd actually tracks all the email (policy with `SASLUsername` track ) and at the 51th email I got the error "Too many Recipient".

No email is actually sent and the counter is now at 50 email/sent.

```
Oct 13 17:49:43 sasl2023.shellrent.com postfix/smtps/smtpd[4151248]: connect from host-X.Y.Z.W.business.telco.org[X.Y.Z.W]
Oct 13 17:49:43 sasl2023.shellrent.com cbpolicyd[4150292]: module=Accounting, mode=update, host=X.Y.Z.W, helo=[192.168.1.199], from=from@domain.tld, to=testemail@0815.ru, reason=accounting_update, policy=1001, accounting=2001, track=SASLUsername:from@domain.tld, period=2023-10-13, count=1/200 (26.0%), size=/-
...
...
...
Oct 13 17:49:43 sasl2023.shellrent.com postfix/smtps/smtpd[4151248]: 510B79E480: client=host-X.Y.Z.W.business.telco.org[X.Y.Z.W], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=from@domain.tld
Oct 13 17:49:43 sasl2023.shellrent.com cbpolicyd[4150292]: module=Accounting, mode=update, host=X.Y.Z.W, helo=[192.168.1.199], from=from@domain.tld, to=testemail@0815.ru0clickemail.com, reason=accounting_update, policy=1001, accounting=2001, track=SASLUsername:from@domain.tld, period=2023-10-13, count=51/200 (26.5%), size=/-
Oct 13 17:49:48 sasl2023.shellrent.com postfix/smtps/smtpd[4151248]: lost connection after RCPT from host-X.Y.Z.W.business.telco.org[X.Y.Z.W]
Oct 13 17:49:48 sasl2023.shellrent.com postfix/smtps/smtpd[4151248]: disconnect from host-X.Y.Z.W.business.telco.org[X.Y.Z.W] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=51 commands=54
```

How can I prevent this? I already tried to play with custom modules in the cluebriger.conf file with no luck.

Here the main.cf, master.cf and cluebringer.conf:

#### main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/cert.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = smtp.server.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, smtp.server.com, smtp.server.com, smtp.server.ip.addr, localhost, 127.0.0.1
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 smtp.server.com smtp.server.com smtp.server.ip.addr smtp.server.com
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
# standard-restrictions-BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
# standard-restrictions-END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
# additional-restrictions-BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
        # reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com,
        # reject_rbl_client hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org
# additional-restrictions-END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
message_size_limit = 40960000
maximal_queue_lifetime = 24h
bounce_queue_lifetime = 3h
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
postscreen_dnsbl_ttl = 1h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_helo_required     = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
default_process_limit = 100
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20
default_destination_rate_delay = 0s
default_destination_recipient_limit = 50
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dh1024.pem
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dh512.pem
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_limit = 50
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
# BEGIN Ansible anvil rate limit
anvil_rate_time_unit = 1h
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = $mynetworks
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 50
# END Ansible anvil rate limit
smtputf8_enable = no
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/smtpd_sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_sender_login_mismatch,
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:10026, inet:dkim.server.com:12345
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:10026, inet:dkim.server.com:12345
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
```

### master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
587     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
465      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
6525      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
smtp-amavis unix - - n - 15 smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=2400
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o max_use=40
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - n - - smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks_style=host
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

### cluebringer.conf

```
[server]

protocols=<<EOT
Postfix
Bizanga
EOT

modules=<<EOT
Core
AccessControl
Accounting
Amavis
CheckHelo
CheckSPF
Greylisting
Quotas
EOT

user=cbpolicyd
group=cbpolicyd

min_servers=8
min_spare_servers=8
max_spare_servers=8
max_servers=100
max_requests=200

log_level=4


log_mail=maillog

[database]
DSN=DBI:mysql:database=policyd;host=localhost
Username=***************
Password=****************

bypass_mode=pass

bypass_timeout=30

[AccessControl]
enable=1


[Accounting]
enable=1


[Amavis]
enable=0 # Disabled by default


[CheckHelo]
enable=0


[CheckSPF]
enable=0


[Greylisting]
enable=1
training_mode=0


[Quotas]
enable=0
```

Thank you for your time.

Due to lack of documentation, tried to play with custom rule and postfix configuration with no luck.